# Powershell - Custom enum as a parameter for a script

Tags: powershell

I have a script with a set of functions and instructions and declared enumeration:

```bsh
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    public enum CleanUpPolicy {
        NoCleanUp,
        CleanUpByExpiration,
        CleanUpByMaxCount
    }
"@
```

and a script parameters with this enum like:

```bsh
param (
    [CleanUpPolicy] $cleanUp = [CleanUpPolicy]::NoCleanUp
)
```

The script works fine when I run it locally. However this script should be downloaded and executed on remote machine and here come issues. 
When I'm doing downloading and execution, I got an error **iex : Unable to find type [CleanUpPolicy]**
Here is script which downloads and executes the script:

```bsh
iwr ("https://<some_url>/test.ps1") | iex
```

What I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think add-type works by compiling the type definition to C#.  Maybe something is going wrong with that.  But in PS 5 you can make enums without using add-type (flags enums too).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum?view=powershell-5.1

```
Enum CleanUpPolicy {
  NoCleanUp
  CleanUpByExpiration
  CleanUpByMaxCount
}


[CleanupPolicy]0
NoCleanUp
```